# Specman E error: Argument to change|fall|rise has to be (short) scalar

Tags: events, specman, e

I have an existing verification environment with simple ports of length `LEN`.
In addition, there are events,that occur when only one of the relevant port's bits rises:

```
  // Port declaration:
    port_a : inout simple_port of uint(bits:LEN) is instance;
    port_b : inout simple_port of uint(bits:LEN) is instance;
    ...

  // Events that use the ports for 1 monitor:
    event event_a is rise (smp.port_a$[idx:idx])@clock;
    event event_b is rise (smp.port_b$[idx:idx])@clock;
```

*** There are many monitors that every one has its own `idx`, `event_a` and `event_b`.

The problem is that I need to change `LEN` define to 64, and all events are now fail since Specman cannot define an event on bus of 64 bits (even though the events are actually "look" only on 1 bit..)

Do you have any idea how to workaround the issue? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this form of defining an event is not supported:

```
event event_a is rise (smp.port_a$[idx:idx])@clock;
```

as bit slice in not supported inside a rise Temporal expression. (it is also documented in the
‘Event’ chapter in the ‘e language referene’.

In a case where you are interested in only one bit of this 64 bit signal you can instead define this port as simple_port of bit
And put the bit slice in the hdl_path as follows:

```
idx:uint(bits:6);
keep idx==34; // the specific bit to this monitor.
port_a : in simple_port of bit is instance;
keep port_a.hdl_path()==read_only(append("signal_name[",idx,":",idx,"]"));
```

then define the event as :

```
event event_a is rise(port_a$)@sim;
```